# Is $(\cos xy^2)u_x - y^2u_y = \tan(x^2 + y^2)$ a linear equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-transformations

My textbook claims the PDE $$(\cos xy^2)u_x - y^2u_y = \tan(x^2 + y^2)$$

is linear. However, if $u$ and $v$ are functions of $x$ and $y$, then $$F(u+v) = (\cos xy)^2(u_x+v_x)-y^2(u_y+v_y)=\tan(x^2+y^2)$$

and yet $$F(u) = (\cos xy^2)u_x - y^2u_y = \tan(x^2 + y^2)$$
$$F(v)=(\cos xy^2)v_x - y^2v_y = \tan(x^2 + y^2)$$

so that $$F(u)+F(v) = (\cos xy^2)(u+v)_x - y^2(u+v)_y = 2\tan(x^2 + y^2)\neq F(u+v)$$
and clearly the equation is not linear.

Comment: A "linear" PDE is (by definition) of the form $Lu=g$ where $L$ is a linear partial differential operator.  So to check linearity, we do not look at the right-hand side.  You are correct: the sum of two solutions of this *inhomogeneous* linear PDE is not again a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *linear* but not *homogenous*.  Linear differential equations are the ones built out of linear differential operators, which are in turn built out of partial differentiation operators and multiplicion operators (which multiply by functions of your independent variables).

If $L$ is a linear operator, then $Lu=f$ is a linear differential equation, and $Lu=0$ is a homogenous linear differential equation.  We need to ask here, "Is there a linear differential operator that makes this of that form?" The answer is yes, we can set

$$L=(\cos xy^2)\partial_x - y^2\partial_y, \qquad f=\tan(x^2 + y^2).$$

When we are linear and homogenous, the sum of any two solutions is a solution.  If $L(u)=0$ and $L(v)=0$, then by linearity, $L(u+v)=L(u)+L(v)=0$.  However, if we are not homogenous, then adding a solution of the corresponding homogenous equation will give a new solution.  So if $L(u)=f$ and $L(v)=0$, then $L(u+v)=L(u)+L(v)=f+0=f$.